# NodeJS: How to generate Rfc2898DeriveBytes like C#?

Tags: c#, node.js

I'm trying to generate the same password hash using NodeJS crypto library and C# Rfc2898DeriveBytes. The NodeJs implementation doesn't generate the same key when using the salt generated from C#. What am I doing wrong? 
In C#:

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        // random khóa 
        using (var rngCryp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var salt = new byte[SaltBytes];
            rngCryp.GetBytes(salt);

            // Hash the password and encode the parameters
            byte[] hash = Rfc2898Deriver(password, salt, Pbkdf2Iterations, HashBytes);

            return Pbkdf2Iterations + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }
    }
private static byte[] Rfc2898Deriver(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputMaxByte)
    {
        using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt))
        {
            deriveBytes.IterationCount = iterations;
            return deriveBytes.GetBytes(outputMaxByte);
        }
    }
```

In NodeJs:

```
export const hash = (text, salt) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  crypto.pbkdf2(text, salt, iterations, bytes, 'sha256', function (err, derivedKey) {
if (err) { reject(err) }
else {
  //return Pbkdf2Iterations + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
  var hash = new Buffer(derivedKey).toString('base64');
  var pass = `${iterations}:${salt}:${hash}`
  resolve(pass);
}});})
```

and use like that:

```
var a = Buffer.from("qcMqVYE0EzAU9Uz+mQxBaKFICG1vR1iq", 'base64')
var a0 = new Buffer("qcMqVYE0EzAU9Uz+mQxBaKFICG1vR1iq")
var pas1 = new Buffer('AL7h8Jx4r8a8PjS5', 'base64')
hash(pas1,a0).then(pass => {
    console.log("pass: ", pass)
    const hashes = crypto.getHashes();
    console.log(hashes); // ['DSA', 'DSA-SHA', 'DSA-SHA1', ...]
    res.send(pass + "\n1000:qcMqVYE0EzAU9Uz+mQxBaKFICG1vR1iq:RkdpgAcpijFqYgVxBCvJugMXqnt4j5f3")
})
```

As you see, hass pass in C# and Nodejs is different.
Node ->

> 1000:qcMqVYE0EzAU9Uz+mQxBaKFICG1vR1iq:D19SUxg6AQxgSLe7YXISPWPvgIoR6BEw

C# ->

> 1000:qcMqVYE0EzAU9Uz+mQxBaKFICG1vR1iq:RkdpgAcpijFqYgVxBCvJugMXqnt4j5f3

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar question and actually your findings helped me a lot.
Looks like the only problem you had is the wrong hashing algorithm that you passed to pbkdf2 function.

Looks like Rfc2898DeriveBytes uses SHA1 by default. So you should have used the smth like that in node:

```
crypto.pbkdf2(text, salt, iterations, bytes, 'sha1', (err, key) => {
    console.log(key.toString('hex'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i entered fix salt, you can also generate random string of 16. You can change length also instead of mine "32".

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
salt = '1234123412341234';
saltString = new Buffer(salt).toString('hex');
var password = 'welcome';
var nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer(password), new Buffer(saltString, 'hex'), 1000, 32, 'sha1');
var hashInHex="00"+saltString+nodeCrypto.toString('hex').toUpperCase();
var FinalHash = Buffer.from(hashInHex, 'hex').toString('base64')
console.log("saltInHex: "+saltString);
console.log("FinalHashInBase64: "+FinalHash);
```

To match stored hash password with user inpur password use bellow code :

```
// NodeJS implementation of crypto, I'm sure google's 
// cryptoJS would work equally well.
var crypto = require('crypto');

// The value stored in [dbo].[AspNetUsers].[PasswordHash]
var hashedPwd = "AGYzaTk3eldHaXkxbDlkQmn+mVJZEjd+0oOcLTNvSQ+lvUQIF1u1CNMs+WjXEzOYNg==";
var hashedPasswordBytes = new Buffer(hashedPwd, 'base64');

var hexChar = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

var saltString = "";
var storedSubKeyString = "";

// build strings of octets for the salt and the stored key
for (var i = 1; i < hashedPasswordBytes.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i <= 16) {
        saltString += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f]
    }
    if (i > 0 && i > 16) {
        storedSubKeyString += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f];
    }
}

// password provided by the user
var password = 'vish@123';

// TODO remove debug - logging passwords in prod is considered 
// tasteless for some odd reason
console.log('cleartext: ' + password);
console.log('saltString: ' + saltString);
console.log('storedSubKeyString: ' + storedSubKeyString);

// This is where the magic happens. 
// If you are doing your own hashing, you can (and maybe should)
// perform more iterations of applying the salt and perhaps
// use a stronger hash than sha1, but if you want it to work
// with the [as of 2015] Microsoft Identity framework, keep
// these settings.
var nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer(password), new Buffer(saltString, 'hex'), 1000, 256, 'sha1');

// get a hex string of the derived bytes
var derivedKeyOctets = nodeCrypto.toString('hex').toUpperCase();

console.log("hex of derived key octets: " + derivedKeyOctets);

// The first 64 bytes of the derived key should
// match the stored sub key
if (derivedKeyOctets.indexOf(storedSubKeyString) === 0) {
    console.info("passwords match!");
} else {
    console.warn("passwords DO NOT match!");
}
```