# How to decrypt data in Node.js encrypted using AES in .NET?

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, encryption, aes

*How to decrypt data in Node.js encrypted using AES in .NET ?*

There are two functions as follow:

1) PasswordEncrypt: to encrypt data

2) PasswordDecrypt: to decrypt data

I am trying to decrypt data in Node.js which is encrypted by using passwordEncrypt function in .NET, I tried to migrate the function as well but I'm unable to find alternative for "new Rfc2898DeriveBytes()" function which is used in both the functions for the sake of cryptographic purpose.

Please note that both the functions for encryption and decryption using AES are added in the code in .NET
and they are working fine.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {             
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "Suraj1234";
            string encrypted_data = "";
            string dencrypted_data = "{'blk_referenceType':'SURVEY','blk_referenceId':10458,'surveyTitle':'','userid':9780206,'role':'Management','FirstName':'Suraj','LastName':'Chandgude','EmailAddress':'','BuildingId':5616,'BuildingName':'H2O Road','OccupancyId':2331719,'UnitName':'Bldg Mgmt','IsMgmtUnit':true,'TimeStampUTC':'2020 - 01 - 24T10: 02:11.0700916Z','expirationdate':'0001 - 01 - 01T00: 00:00','language':'en - US'}";
            encrypted_data = passwordEncrypt(dencrypted_data, EncryptionKey);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypt DATA - " + encrypted_data);
            dencrypted_data = passwordDecrypt(encrypted_data, EncryptionKey);
            Console.WriteLine("DECRYPTED DATA - " + dencrypted_data);
        }

         public static string passwordEncrypt(string inText, string key)
        {
            byte[] bytesBuff = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inText);
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
                aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                        cStream.Close();
                    }
                    inText = Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return inText;
        }

        public static string passwordDecrypt(string cryptTxt,string key)
        {
        cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace(" ", "+");
            cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace("%20", "+");
            cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace("%2F", "/");
            byte[] bytesBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptTxt);
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
                aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                        cStream.Close();
                    }
                    cryptTxt = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(mStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return cryptTxt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [NodeJS: How to generate Rfc2898DeriveBytes like C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887002/nodejs-how-to-generate-rfc2898derivebytes-like-c)?

Comment: Yes Andrew, but didn't worked that way.

Comment: Can you explain _what_ is not working? Are the derived key and IV different in both codes? Please post your most recent NodeJS code.